# Spring Kafka Consumer/Listener Group

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

what is the difference in specifying group at the consumer

```
spring.kafka.consumer.group-id
```

vs specifying at the @KafkaListener?

```
@KafkaListener(topic="test", group = "test-grp")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the javadocs for the `group` property; it has nothing to do with the kafka `group.id`...

```
/**
 * If provided, the listener container for this listener will be added to a bean
 * with this value as its name, of type {@code Collection<MessageListenerContainer>}.
 * This allows, for example, iteration over the collection to start/stop a subset
 * of containers.
 * @return the bean name for the group.
 */
```

This has been renamed `containerGroup` in 1.3/2.0.

Those release versions also provide...

```
/**
 * Override the {@code group.id} property for the consumer factory with this value
 * for this listener only.
 * @return the group id.
 * @since 1.3
 */
String groupId() default "";

/**
 * When {@link #groupId() groupId} is not provided, use the {@link #id() id} (if
 * provided) as the {@code group.id} property for the consumer. Set to false, to use
 * the {@code group.id} from the consumer factory.
 * @return false to disable.
 * @since 1.3
 */
boolean idIsGroup() default true;
```

Previously, you needed a container factory/consumer factory for each listener; these allow you to use one factory instance and override the `group.id`.

Comment: Thanks @Gary Russel. I had gone through the docs but it wasn't clear. "Previously, you needed a container factory/consumer factory for each listener; these allow you to use one factory instance and override the group.id." This clarification helped me.